# Any function or method by which I can save the new modified data to the xml file from which it is retrieved or loaded?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can I save the modified data to the same xml file after loading from that external xml file in  ActionScript3.

Is there exist any function or method or any way to save the modified data again in the same file from which it was loaded.

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "sample.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{               
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
    trace("Data loaded.");

trace(myXML); //showing output of just loaded xml file.

//process of adding new child node or property.
var newnode:XML = new XML(); 
    newnode =
        <student >
            <sname srno="2">mm</sname>
            <father tax="no">
                <fname>Ratan</fname>
                <focc>business man</focc>
                <mobno>9928946899</mobno>
            </father>
        </student>;

    myXML = myXML.appendChild(newnode);

trace(myXML); //showing o/p after being the child-node appended.
}
```

where the sample.xml file located in the same working path, contains only the following data.-

```
<data>
  <student srno="1" class="5" rollno="1">
    <sname>Rohan Jain</sname>
    <father tax="yes">
      <fname>Ronak Jain</fname>
      <focc>teacher</focc>
      <mobno>9928946899</mobno>
    </father>
  </student>
</data>
```

Comment: If you're building a browser based application; nothing you can do on the client will save the file to a specific name and location.  You'll have to send your updated doc to the server for saving. If you want to save the file to the client amchine; then you cannot do so w/o user input and there is no way to guarantee what the user will name it or where they'll put it.

Comment: Hey Jeffry, it could be a nice answer

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik Okay, I formalized it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're building a browser based application; nothing you can do on the client will save the file to a specific name and location. You'll have to send your updated doc to the server for saving.  It is easy to write a service to do this in most server side languages I have dealt with.

If you want to save the file to the client machine; you can do so using [FileReference.save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29).  However, this requires user input and there is no way to guarantee what the user will name the file or where they'll put it.